# EDIT: how to automatically add data from a field when called

Tags: php, mysql

how to automatically add data from a field when called.
example:
value of `field` is = `1AA/example/example`

iam using foreach

```
foreach ($datanomor as $row){
$var=$row->MaxCode;
echo $var;
}
```

the result is

```
1AA/example/example
```

i want to add operation on `(1+ 1AA/example/example)`

so what must i do when i call the field, result will show:

```
2AA/example/example
```

***edit
have table with name  `t_surat_keluar`

and query to call value of field in my controller is :

```
$datanomor = $this->db->query("SELECT max(nomor_surat) as maxKode")
    ->('FROM t_surat_keluar where id_jenissurat=$row->id_jenissurat')
    ->result();
$data['datanomor']=$datanomor;
```

the value is `001/smk/ck/2018`

In my view i run this script to call that value:

```
foreach ($datanomor1 as $row) {
    $var = $row->maxKode;
    echo $var;
}
```

Now I want to ask, how can I change directly that value `(001/smk/ck/2018)` to `(002/smk/ck/2018)` when i calling from script ?.

sorry my english is bad.

***edit now i can change directly that value with this script

```
foreach ($datanomor1 as $row){
$var=$row->maxKode;
$var[2] = (int)$var[2]+1;
 echo $var;
            }
```

the new problem is when last value `(009/smk/ck/2018)` if i use this script:

```
$var[2] = (int)$var[2]+1;
```

output will show `(**001**/smk/ck/2018)` not `(**0010**/smk/ck/2018)`

Comment: So do you want result like 11AA/example/example?

Comment: no, i want the result 2AA/example/example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
foreach ($datanomor as $row){
    echo preg_replace_callback('/^([0-9]+)(.+)/', function($matches) {
        return ($matches[1] + 1) . $matches[2];
    }, $row->MaxCode);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As i understood u want to make operation on the first char on ur var so u can select it as char from var

```
foreach ($datanomor as $row){
$var=$row->MaxCode;
//select the first char and casting it to integer then increment it 
$var[0] = (int)$var[0]++;

echo $var;
}
```

Comment: it will not work:-https://3v4l.org/aF7oL . you need to do `+1` instead of `++` .check here:- https://3v4l.org/1Aohr

Comment: this is most efficient solution among all by changing `++` to `+1`. So +1

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
$varInt = intval($var);
$varString = strval($varInt);
$varInt += 1;

$result = strval($varInt).substr($var, strlen($varString));
```

No elegant, but should work.